# Different Dictionary Implementations

Tags: data-structures, dictionary

I am preparing for an exam in algorithm analysis and after I have learned C# and implemented Dictionary in different ways I am confused about the advantages/disadvantages..

So here are my questions:

What is a reason to implement a Dictionary using unordered array instead of always sorted array?

Reaons to implement Dicitonary using always sorted array instead of unordered array?

Reasons to implement Dictionary using a Binary Search Tree instead of an always sorted array?

Comment: Which impl inserts/deletes/lookups quickest? Which uses least memory? What's C# got to do with it?

Comment: Not trying to nag, but be careful with your terminology around Arrays, Lists, and Dictionaries. In C# (and most other languages) a Dictionary usually entails the use of keys in which case look-ups are done by hashing rather then searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an unordered array you can just tack items onto the end or copy the array into a new array and tack items on the end if the original fills up. O(1) or O(n) depending on these 2 cases to insert, but O(n) to do any lookups.

With an ordered array you COULD gain the ability to more quickly search it depending on its contents, either through a binary search or other cool searches, but it has increased insertion cost because you must move things around in the array every time you insert into it, unless you're only adding things already in sorted order, which case it might even be the worst case which would be O(n) for each element.

With a binary search tree you can easily find whatever node you're looking for based on whatever you're forking the tree on in O(log n) time, though this is only possible on a balanced binary tree. With an unbalanced binary search tree (basically a linked list) you could get worst case performance of O(n). With the balanced tree though, an insertion can be more expensive because it requires reorganizing the tree which is usually O(n log n), but again O is the worst case scenario, most balanced binary search trees can do most insertions more quickly.

Comment: thank you for summarizing. I am unsure though of how you come up with the costs...I know what the costs are of sorting an array using different sort algorithms but is the cost the same to sort a tree?